# How to calculate parts of a timestamp

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with my code. I have to datetime values as a string. I want to calculate the
time passed between them. I can archive this with the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
tstamp1 = datetime.strptime('2021-02-20 12:25:08', fmt)
tstamp2 = datetime.strptime('2021-02-20 11:19:17', fmt)
td = tstamp1 - tstamp2
```

The result I get is 1:05:51.

Now I have another value as string: 00:58:08

Here I also want to know how many time passed between them:

1:05:51 - 00:58:08.

I need the result formated like this: 00:07:43

I really dont know how to do this. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You may have a look at `datetime.timedelta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help your requirement.

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
tstamp1 = datetime.strptime('2021-02-20 12:25:08', fmt)
tstamp2 = datetime.strptime('2021-02-20 11:19:17', fmt)
td = tstamp1 - tstamp2
tr = '00:58:08'

tr = datetime.strptime(str(tr), '%H:%M:%S')
td = datetime.strptime(str(td), '%H:%M:%S')

ans = td - tr
print(ans)
```